# Update NPM modules from within grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to automate the update of new node modules but, npm update seems not to want to run correctly from within grunt also updating the package.json file with the new version. I want to do this regardless of what version is specified in the package.json file.

What I found till now is the node module: npm-check-updates (https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)

The problem is that I can't get it to work with other modules like npm-shell or npm-exec.

I've tried using npm update -D directly, but that fails too.

I'm asking if it can be done.

Here's what I use:

```
grunt.registerTask('update', 'Update npm modules', function() {
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var cb = this.async();
    exec('npm update -D', {}, function(err, stdout) {
        console.log(stdout);
        cb();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm correct you're trying to update ALL of your npm packages inside of your package.json file? I would recommend using this package.

Install the package.

```
npm install grunt-auto-install --save-dev
```

Add it to your grunt tasks.

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-auto-install');
```

Then add the configuration to your gruntfile.js

```
grunt.initConfig({
  auto_install: {
    local: {},
    subdir: {
      options: {
        cwd: 'subdir',
        stdout: true,
        stderr: true,
        failOnError: true,
        npm: '--production'
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Here is the reference:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-auto-install

**AFTER YOUVE UPDATED THE PACKAGES**
Update your devDependencies and dependencies automatically with a grunt task.
Install the npm module to update your packages in your dev dependencies object.

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-dev-update
```

Add it to your grunt tasks.

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-dev-update');
```

Add your configuration to your gruntfile.

```
devUpdate: {
        main: {
            options: {
                //task options go here 
            }
        }
    }
```

Reference:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-dev-update

Comment: I'm trying to do a update to the latest version of my NPM modules and update the package.json with the new version as well.

Comment: The module you specify doesn't do that. It just installs / updates modules according to the package.json file.

Comment: The first Grunt task updates all of your npm modules. The second grunt task updates your package.json file.

Comment: Thanks, I still use my method, but your answer is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using npm-check-update (ncu) and grunt.util.spawn:

```
// Install NPM Updates
grunt.registerTask('update-npm', 'Update package.json and update npm modules', function() {
    grunt.log.writeln('If you get an error here, run "npm install -g npm-check-updates".');
    grunt.task.run('npm-write-new');
    grunt.task.run('npm-update');
});
// Check for npm module updates
grunt.registerTask('npm-check', 'Check for npm modules updates', function() {
    var done = this.async();

    grunt.log.writeln('Checking for npm modules updates ...');

    grunt.util.spawn({
        cmd: 'ncu',
        args: '',
        opts: {
            stdio: 'inherit',
        }
    }, function () {
        grunt.log.writeln('No files were modified.');
        done();
    });
});
// Write new versions to packages.json
grunt.registerTask('npm-write-new', 'Write new versions to package.json', function() {
    var done = this.async();

    grunt.log.writeln('Checking for npm modules updates ...');

    grunt.util.spawn({
        cmd: 'ncu',
        args: ['-u'],
        opts: {
            stdio: 'inherit',
        }
    }, function () {
        grunt.log.writeln('New versions were written to "package.json".');
        done();
    });
});
// Update npm modules
grunt.registerTask('npm-update', 'Update npm modules', function() {
    var done = this.async();

    grunt.log.writeln('Installing npm modules updates ...');

    grunt.util.spawn({
        cmd: 'npm',
        args: ['update','--loglevel','warn'],
        opts: {
            stdio: 'inherit',
        }
    }, function () {
        grunt.log.writeln('NPM modules were updated.');
        done();
    });
});
```